# How to send tinymce editor's style to preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, tinymce

I've made a custom colorsplit button on editor's toolbar that changes page's background color. I've learned that tinymce grabs only content of editor and sends it to document preview which is iframe. How do I make tinymce send not only content but style too?

Here's example code for changing background:

```
o.onselect = function (c) {

    ed.dom.setStyle(ed.dom.getRoot(),'background',c);

};
```

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414332/how-to-change-background-of-tinymce

Comment: I've already made my button to change backgroudn color. Now I need to send this color to my document preview area.